# What are the reserved keywords in Coq?

Tags: coq

I would like to have a list of all of the keywords in Coq that cannot be used as identifier names.

https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#lexical-conventions provides a list of keywords that are reserved in Gallina, but it does not include the keyword 'by'.

Nevertheless, `Definition by:=O` does not compile, and gives the error `Syntax error: [Prim.ident_decl] expected after [def_token] (in [vernac:gallina]).`. This indicates that the above keyword list is not complete, so if anyone has a complete list, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/a37d1c0e433f34d0ab5357b1f78eb0e04d961dc8/plugins/ssr/ssrvernac.mlg#L616) says that Coq uses `by` as a (true) keyword since 8.3.

It seems that the Ltac plugin makes the corresponding declaration [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/a37d1c0e433f34d0ab5357b1f78eb0e04d961dc8/plugins/ltac/pptactic.ml#L442), because if we switch the plugin off, then `by` can be used again:

```
coqtop -noinit
Welcome to Coq 8.9.0 (April 2019)

Coq < Inductive T := t.
T is defined
T_rect is defined
T_ind is defined
T_rec is defined

Coq < Definition by := t.
by is defined
```

Comment: The OP is saying the particular list appears to be not complete.

Comment: Yes, @Bubbler is correct. That list is not complete, as it does not contain the keyword 'by'.

Comment: @DarbyHaller, My apologizes for completely misreading your question. Please see  the update.

Comment: @Bubbler Thank you for bringing it to my attention. Updated.